# Cleaning up the HTML generated by JQueryUI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can this be done? I'm building a template generator complete with resizable and draggable elements inside a preview window. Problem is, when I go to get the HTML generated, each of the elements have all the JQueryUI classes and divs added, which are not desirable in the final product. I'd like the output HTML to be simple enough that I can scale up positions and sizes so that it could be its own page, but I can't find a way to keep the preview window as customizable as possible and still get clean HTML out of it. Anybody ever done something like this before? thoughts? ideas? Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
In other words, I want to somehow process this html:

```
<div id="preview_title" value="Title" class="ui-draggable ui-resizable" style="visibility: visible; ">Title<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" unselectable="on"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" unselectable="on"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 1001; " unselectable="on"></div></div>
            <div id="preview_logo" value="Logo" class="ui-draggable ui-resizable" style="visibility: visible; ">Logo<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" unselectable="on"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" unselectable="on"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 1001; " unselectable="on"></div></div>
            <div id="preview_ticker" value="Ticker" class="ui-draggable ui-resizable" style="visibility: visible; ">Ticker<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" unselectable="on"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" unselectable="on"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 1001; " unselectable="on"></div></div>
            <div id="preview_clock" value="Clock" class="ui-draggable ui-resizable" style="visibility: visible; ">Clock<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" unselectable="on"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" unselectable="on"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 1001; " unselectable="on"></div></div>
```

and end up with something more like this:

```
<div id="preview_title" value="Title" style="visibility: visible; width: 400px; height: 16px; top: 32px; left: 12px; ">Title</div>
            <div id="preview_logo" value="Logo" style="visibility: visible; width: 50px; height: 50px; top: 123px; left: 16px; ">Logo</div>
            <div id="preview_ticker" value="Ticker" style="visibility: visible; width: 400px; height: 32px; top: 12px; left: 12px; ">Ticker</div>
            <div id="preview_clock" value="Clock" style="visibility: visible; width: 45px; height: 45px; top: 12px; left: 100px; ">Clock</div>
```

Comment: Are you saying that the output would not be resizable, draggable, etc?

Comment: right, i want the output to be the result of the resizing and dragging the user did before they hit the 'generate HTML' button.

Comment: how come this got voted down? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For almost each Jquery UI object you can call a 'destroy' method that removes all the special html.

Comment: However, I don't know if calling destroy will keep the data that you want.

Comment: It does, thankfully. I'm getting exactly what I want, thanks Zippy.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove the element from DOM, jQuery has a method for [empty](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) and [remove](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

Example for a jQuery dialog (say you want multiple dialogs over the same div:

```
<div class="someFancyDialog">
    <label class="name"></label>
     ...
</div>
$(.someFancyDialog).bind('dialogclose', function(event, ui)
{
    $(event.target).empty().remove();
}
$(.someFancyDialog).dialog();
```

In this way, you are sure that the DOM remains clean after the dialog is destroyed.